# Passing a Struct Array to constructor of Solidity Contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I am building an NFT smart contract with solidity, and I am trying to pass and Array of Structs into the constructor when I deploy the contract. However I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The contact code is:

```
contract MetropolisWorldGenesis {

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    struct PropertyAttributes {
        uint id;
        string name;
        string description;
        string image;
        Properties properties;
    }

    struct Properties {
        string tower;
        string disctrict;
        string neighborhood;
        string primary_type;
        string sub_type_1;
        string sub_type_2;
        string structure;
        string feature_1;
        string feature_2;
        string feature_3;
        string feature_4;
        string feature_5;
        string rarity;
        // string internal_id;
    }

    //store a list of all the NFT's available to mint. 
    //this is built on when the constructor is called. 
    PropertyAttributes[] defaultProperties;

    //store which has been minted. 
    mapping(uint => bool) public MintedNfts;

    //map the nft tokenid to the atributes 
    mapping(uint256 => PropertyAttributes) public nftAttributes;

    constructor(PropertyAttributes[] memory props) { 
        console.log("OK I am making the contract, just this once mind");

        for (uint i = 0; i < props.length; i += 1){
             defaultProperties.push(props[i]);

             PropertyAttributes memory p = defaultProperties[i];
             console.log("Done initializing %s w/ HP %s, img %s", p.name, p.description, p.image);
        
    } 
}
```

and I am calling it using the following:

```
const main = async () => {

    // make up the data from t he json 
    const nftList = require('./nft_list_finalv2.json')
    
    let props = []

    for(var i=0; i < nftList['nfts'].length;i+=1){
        
        x = nftList['nfts'][i]['metadata']
        props.push(x)
    }
    
    console.log(props.length)

    // deply the contract will the data made above. 
    const propertyContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('MetropolisWorldGenesis');
    const propertyContract = await propertyContractFactory.deploy(
        props
    );
    await propertyContract.deployed();
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", propertyContract.address);
  };
  
  const runMain = async () => {
    try {
      await main();
      process.exit(0);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };
  
  runMain();
```

The Json file is an arrary of items structured as follows.

```
{ 'nfts':[
     {
            "id": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "tester",
                "description": "Rtestt",
                "image": "",
                "properties": {
                    "tower": "Tower 1",
                    "district": "Hir",
                    "neighborhood": "Fres",
                    "primary_type": "Whause",
                    "sub_type_1": "Aboned",
                    "sub_type_2": "Fors",
                    "structure": "Dark brick",
                    "feature_1": "Df",
                    "feature_2": "Gins",
                    "feature_3": "Castes",
                    "feature_4": "Cloors",
                    "feature_5": "e walls",
                    "rarity": "",
                    "internal_id": "Tower 1_1"
                }
            },
            "price": 10,
            "ipfs": "",
            "img_name": "WqmYMT02j.png",
            "map_ref": "Z"
        },
....
]}
```

I get the array of data fine on javascript side but seems to be some error as i pass it into the contract.
What am i missing here?

Comment: What is the contents of the `./nft_list_finalv2.json` file?

Comment: I've edited the question to include json format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Last time I checked there was no way to pass a `struct` to a `constructor function` ([see here this 2018 answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/44102)). It says that:

> ...you cannot pass struct to a constructor as it will be receiving its input outside from the blockchain. Only the private and internal functions can expect structs as input parameters.

The solution is to use "primitive" data types as inputs. For your particular case the constructor function could be modified to accept one NFT object like:

```
constructor (
  int NFTsId,
  int MetaId,
  string MetaName,
  string MetaDescription,
  string MetaImage,
  string PropertiesTower,
  string PropertiesDistrict,
  ...,
  uint MetaPrice,
  string MetaIPFS,
  ...
) {
  // Assign values
}
```

Or you can write the constructor function to receive multiple inputs in arrays and relocate them according to their index position (the first MetaId goes with the first MetaName...):

```
constructor (
  int[] memory NFTsIds,
  int[] memory MetaIds,
  string[] memory MetaNames,
  string[] memory MetaDescriptions,
  string[] memory MetaImages,
  string[] memory PropertiesTowers,
  string[] memory PropertiesDistricts,
  ...,
  uint[] memory MetaPrices,
  string[] memory MetaIPFSs,
  ...
) {  
  for (uint256 i=0; i < NFTsId.length; i ++){
    NFTsId = NFTsIds[i];
    ...
    // Assign values
  }
}
```

It is important to point out that the `for` loop that would consume considerable amounts of gas depending on the amount of NFTs objects send to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks very much that makes sense, originally I had the array approach but I ran into a an stack too deep error which I hoped to fix with the structs, looks like i'll need a full rethink.

Comment: I'm using 0.8.9 and I don't have any issue passing structs as constructor parameters. I'm using structs exactly to avoid a stack too deep error. The issue I'm having is that I now get an error when verifying on Etherscan. I'm trying to figure out if this is related.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can in fact pass a struct as an arg to a constructor in solidity. I'm doing it myself in one of my contracts:

```js
struct UserConfig {
        address user;
        address userToken;
        uint userSlippage; 
    }

    struct FixedConfig { 
        address inbox;
        address ops;
        address PYY;
        address emitter;
        uint maxGas;
    }

FixedConfig fxConfig;
VariableConfig varConfig;


constructor(
        FixedConfig memory fxConfig_,
        VariableConfig memory varConfig_
    ) {
        fxConfig = fxConfig_;
        varConfig = varConfig_;
    }
```

You'd pass it as an array on ethers.js.

The problem that I'm having, and how I ended up in this post in the first place, is that when you pass the array to `deploy()` on ethers, it changes the order of the vars on the struct in the contract. So I'm trying to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: thanks that is good to know. Any joy with the order issue?

Comment: No idea on that one

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. Ethers/Hardhat -> solidity keeps the order. What solidity version are you using?

Comment: sol 0.8.14 @ian

Comment: What do you mean with "You'd pass it as an array on ethers.js"? How does the contract know it is an array if you just declare it as a normal struct there?

Comment: Don't know how the contract knows it, but just that it does. Try it out yourself and you'll see @FalconStakepool

Answer (score 0):

You can pass struct to a external and public visibility function as well. 
If your function is something like this:

```
struct YourStruct {
    uint x;
    string y;
}
function func(
    uint a,
    uint b,
    string memory c,
    YourStruct memory d
    ) external;
```

Then you can pass these like this:

```
let args = [
    1,
    2,
    "c",
    {
        x: 3,
        y: "y"
    }
]
contract.func(...args);
```

Only struct needs an object with key value pair, you can follow this for nested structs also. 
I hope it'll help!